# Вывести уникальные ID действующих клиентов, у которых отсутствует услуга "Услуга_3"

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите не могу связать все воедино, чтобы вышел запрос

```
Select DISTINCT c.ClientID
from Clients as c
where DateTo = '31.12.9999' -- возвращает уникальных пользователей
```

как убрать из выборки всех пользователей тех, у кого есть услуга 3?

```
select distinct ClientID
from Products
where ProductType = 'Услуга_3' -- возвращает пользователей, у которых есть услуга 3
```

```
select distinct ClientID --возвращает всех пользователей
from Products
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое — написать ровно то, что вам нужно:

```
Select DISTINCT c.ClientID
from Clients as c
where DateTo = '31.12.9999'
  and not exists(select 1 from Products where ClientID = c.ClientID AND ProductType='Услуга_3')
```

Можно использовать join

```
Select DISTINCT c.ClientID
from Clients as c
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.ClientID = c.ClientID AND p.ProductType = 'Услуга_3'
WHERE p.ProductType IS NULL
  AND c.DateTo = '31.12.9999'
```

Comment: в таком случае он выводит клиента под номером 1, а правильный ответ должен быть клиент 2 , он активный и у него нет услуг 3

Comment: Хм, надо бы вам заменить слово «вычленить» в вопросе

Comment: Select DISTINCT c.ClientID
from Clients as c
where DateTo = '31.12.9999'
  and exists(select 1 from Products where ClientID = c.ClientID AND ProductType='Услуга_3') верный только надо поставить не exists , а not exists